# xcode9 permission denied when ibm tool project load

Tags: ios, iphone, ibm-mobilefirst

buildtime.sh: Permission denied

DONE with script: buildtime.sh (exitStatus=126)\n\n

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open terminal and paste this command

```
chmod a+x "<complete path of your file>"
```

It will give all rights to the file.

Comment: solved my issue...just set run script only when installing.hope so it help someone also..

Comment: Glad to hear that...you can accept this answer...:)

Comment: same problem occur when archive the app now what i do for this?